# How to implement Before Filter Functionality in Symfony 2.3.7

Tags: symfony

Hi I have a function as following which used to check for existence of financial year. I want to call it on before any Controller action I execute. I mean I want to keep it a place where it execute at each time when user go to any controller in my application.

```
public function checkFinancialYear($dm) {
    $getFinancialYear = $dm->getRepository('EduAccountBundle:FinancialYear')
        ->findBy(array('isDeleted' => false));

    if (count($getFinancialYear) < 1) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

I am unable to find best solution for this in Symfony 2.3.7. Please help, how can I implement it so that I do not need to call it again into every controller.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Evrything is here :

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html

You had to create an event listener, and do what you want in.